# Codeblocks opens empty files and throws linking error

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks

Everytime I compile something via Codeblocks 10.05 and MinGWs GNU-CPP-Compiler. Everything works fine. Then I get linking errors, that there are no references to 'MyNamespace::MyClass'. When I click on the error, it opens an empty file. So it seems to try to compile empty files. This bug is there since 2 or 3 days and it only happens on GUI-projects oder Console-Applications-projects. This bug already has been reported and I tried the latest nightly. It didn't helped.
How can I fix this or link on an other way ?

Edit1:
After a hint/remark I tried to recreate this error, but the simple project worked. So does anyone has an idea how it can produced? In this time I'll try to find files that creates this behaviour.

Edit2:
I failed very hard. Sample:

```
// hpp
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass;
    extern MyClass globalMyClass;
}

// cpp
MyNamespace::MyClass globalMyClass;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not your code? Can you paste an example program?

Comment: @jrok The current program has about 12000 lines of code and I don't really want to publish it. So I tried to recreate this issue, but it works. **Updated my question**

Comment: Well, in your sample there's no definition, only extern declaration and a forward declaration. Naturally, the linker will complain about undefined reference.

Comment: @jrok that's what it said the whole time. The question is answered, but I can't flag it as answered. In this example it's jast a forward declaration, in real it's filled with stuff.